# Append prefix to every line of every file in a folder

Tags: powershell, function, addition, prefix

I am rather new at programming and looking for your help there. I have a folder that contains multiple files, as shown below :

[image]

For instance, one of them contains this :

```
ACICV1DATCOUREC      20220517091400  1         0
ACICV1DATCOUREC      20220517093200  0         0
```

I would like to happen the prefix `FOSN@SOLF@GENERAL@` in front of each line of each file within that folder so that they look like this (e.g the one above):

```
FOSN@SOLF@GENERAL@ACICV1DATCOUREC      20220517091400  1         0
FOSN@SOLF@GENERAL@ACICV1DATCOUREC      20220517093200  0         0
```

Could you please tell me which functions (PowerShell, Python, Script,...) might be best suited to do so?

Thank you very much in advance for your help

Comment: Don't ask for multiple script languages. Ask for just one. If you want multiple, ask a separate question for each script language you want. Questions on Stack Overflow should be focused.

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell you can use [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) to enumerate the text files and [`Rename-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item?view=powershell-7.2) to rename them.

```sh
(Get-ChildItem C:\path\to\files -Filter *.txt) |
    Rename-Item -NewName { 'FOSN@SOLF@GENERAL@' + $_.Name }
```

Comment: I would put the `Get-ChildItem C:\path\to\files -Filter *.txt` line between brackets to avoid re-renaming files

Comment: @Theo between brackets? you mean like a `|? { -not $_.Name.StartsWith(...` ?

Comment: No, like `(Get-ChildItem C:\path\to\files -Filter *.txt) | Rename-Item ...`. That way, the iteration is all done before renaming. Otherwise, Get-ChildItem is likely to pick up files that are already renamed again (and again). This wouldn't be necessary if the OP didn't obscure the filenames in his screenshot so you can have a better filter like `ACICV1DATCOUREC*.txt`, but since he left that blurred, `*.txt` is the best thing here.

Comment: @Theo I thought that would only happen if using `-Recurse` ?

Comment: I did see it happen when there are a lot of files inside the folder though with or without  recursion..

Comment: @Theo all right, thanks for the clarification, I'm not sure if I ever came across that without `-Recurse`, guessing if the path has wildcard metachars like `[` and `]` but a file with `*` wouldn't be possible in Windows I think

Comment: Wait... why is this about renaming? I'm pretty sure the question is about file _contents_.